# The number $2^p-2$

Tags: number-theory

Suppose $p$ is a prime number. 
Use computer, for all $p<10^7$, I find that almost all the valuation of $2^p-2$ at $p$ is one, only two exceptions: $p=1093$ or $3511$, at these two primes the valuation are both $2$. I don't know why.

Are there only finitely many primes $p$ such that $ord_p(2^p-2)>1$？ Does there exist at least one prime $p$ such that $ord_p(2^p-2)=3$? etc.

Are there some relative references for those problem?

Thank you for any comments!

Comment: Try OEIS at https://oeis.org/search?q=1093%2C+3511&language=english&go=Search for references

Comment: @MarkBennet, Thank you! I accept your comment as an answer. From the link, I found that what　I ask is whether the "Wieferich primes" is finitely many. And wiki says: "As of October 2013, the only known Wieferich primes are 1093 and 3511 (sequence A001220 in OEIS)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments:

The [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org) is a good first place to go with a question like this. The narrative can be quite terse, but there is often a huge amount of information, including related sequences and references. The two you have found are the only ones known (none, therefore, for exponent $3$).

Here it reveals that the key idea in prior research is Wieferich Primes (the $p^2$ case). The [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wieferich_prime) gives some additional background and context.